# turning a weighted edgelist into an unweighted in r

Tags: r, social-networking, igraph, sna

I have data on every interaction that could and did happen at a university club weekly social hour

```
id1     id2   timestalked   date  
 1       2       1         1/1/2010
 1       3       0         1/1/2010
...
100     2        4         1/8/2010
...
```

I want to first load this in as a directed graph for the entire time period for visualization. For the weighted matrix I did.

```
library(igraph);
el <- read.csv("el.csv", header = TRUE);
G <- graph.data.frame(el,directed=TRUE);
A <- as_adjacency_matrix(G,type="both",names=TRUE,sparse=FALSE,attr="timestalked");
```

I thought removing `attr="timestalked"` would turn the weights > 0 into 1 but that does not seem to work

```
library(igraph);
el <- read.csv("el.csv", header = TRUE);
G_unweight <- graph.data.frame(el,directed=TRUE);
A_unweight <- as_adjacency_matrix(G_unweight,type="both",names=TRUE,sparse=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`as_adjacency_matrix()` doesn't provide any argument to control weights. Note that it just provides the number of edges between nodes from the graph.

To turn the weighted edgelist into an unweighted one, try this

```
A <- as_adjacency_matrix(G, type = "both", names = TRUE, sparse = FALSE)
A[A > 1] <- 1
```

Note that you can also use the `graph_from_adjacency_matrix()` function to create an unweighted `igraph` graph from the adjacency matrix by specifying `weighted = NULL`.

Comment: Am I right in assuming that a weight of 0 does not draw a link between A and B? My weights are the number of interactions and I want the 0s to lead to no link

Comment: Yes, it's because after using `as_adjacency_matrix()`, 0s lead to no interaction (edge) between nodes.